# NSUserDefaults do not save in iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7, nsuserdefaults

In iOS6 the following code works fine. After the first launch, the hasLoaded BOOL is YES.

```
BOOL hasLoaded = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kUserDefaultFirstLaunch];

    if (!hasLoaded){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kUserDefaultFirstLaunch];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

       //do first launch stuff

    }
```

But in iOS7, every time I run the app, hasLoaded is NO, even though I'm clearly setting it to YES and synchronizing. I have seen a couple other posts about this but no solutions. This would be such a HUGE bug that I can't believe it's really an Apple bug. Please tell me I'm wrong. Is it really true that no apps can reliably use NSUserDefaults on iOS7?

I've tested this on both the simulator and the device.

Comment: That code works as expected on my iOS 7 Simulator.

Comment: Have you looked at the `NSUserDefaults` file?

Comment: Checking the user defaults file is a good suggestion (you find it in Library/Preferences in the application bundle). - And just to make sure: Is that your real unmodified code? How is kUserDefaultFirstLaunch defined? Did you test it with a new app containing nothing else?

Comment: Also inspecting `dictionaryRepresentation` at runtime helps finding wrong values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the com.domain.myapp.plist file in the Preferences folder I saw that the kUserDefaultFirstLaunch was actually "2", which is neither true or false. Turns out that I had a typo elsewhere that was using the kUserDefaultFirstLaunch key.

Dumb mistake, but I'm glad it's not a bug in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I think adding the following to the `Application Delegate` was what fixed it:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried, and it still is not persisting.

Answer (score -1):

Take your value in string(or any other as per your requirement) and save the string in user defaults

```
NSUserDefaults *userdefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];        
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dicUser objectForKey:@"device_token"]];
[userdefault setObject:str forKey:@"YOURKEY"];
```